# extracting a specific cell when specific column and row paramteres are met

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that contains 16 columns and 100 rows. In each cell is a specific number.

The header columns contain specified numbers as do the row headers.

On a seperate sheet within the workbook is a calculator that people can input numbers to calculate engine perfomance figures.

What i am after is that when a specific number is inputed corresponding to a number in the header column, along with a specific number from the row header the number corresponding to the interestion of those two numbers will automaically populate in the calculator cell sheet.

I am very new to excel, and have had minimal experience in writing or inputting code.

Any assistance in this would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I assume your data sheet looks something like this but with more columns and more rows. You can use a combination of VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP to achieve what you want.

In my example the formula in D11 is:

```
=VLOOKUP(D9,A1:F6,(HLOOKUP(D10,A1:F6,1,TRUE) + 1),TRUE)
```

You need to change the parameters of this to match your dataset, the user inputs in D9 and D10 and the product is displayed in D11.

Comment: Thanks Alistair, How can i get this happening between two sheets within the same workbook? The table is in 1 worksheet titled "Calculated MGT Table" with the user interface in another worksheet titled "Calculating Table" Is there a way i can attach a screen shot of my spreadsheets so you can have a beeter idae of what i am trying to achieve?

Comment: You can add a screenshot by editing your original question and uploading the image.

Comment: This system will not let me upload a screen shot of the spreadsheet attached to a word doc?

Comment: Just upload a jpg by clicking the image icon in the edit menu and search for the file.

Comment: well since im new on this site i cannot post images of the spreadsheet. Thanks for your help Alistair, i will have to try by playing around with the formula you and Barry have provided.

Comment: Where I have `A1:F6` you should use 'Calculated MGT Table'!A1:P100` assuming your 16 columns and 100 rows start from A1. Place the formula in the Calculating Table worksheet, I'm sure there must be an appropriate cell within the table to display the output answer.

Comment: @Alistair Weir - I'm not sure this will work as required if data differs, your version relies on the values in the column headers being integers starting at 1, if that isn't the case then the formula won't work, better to use MATCH in place of HLOOKUP then the numbers can be anything you want....

Comment: Good point, if the numbers in the column header are not ordered integers this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The "standard" approach is to use `INDEX` with two `MATCH` functions based on column and row headers, e.g.

`=INDEX(Table_without_headers,MATCH(Z2,row_headers,0),MATCH(Z3,column_headers,0))`

where Z2 and Z3 contain the search values

Comment: Thanks Barry, where abouts do i place this formula? Sorry but i am very new at Excel

Comment: You can put this formula anywhere you want! Assuming you name the different parts of the table as indicated (select range, right-click and use "Name a range") then you can use the formula in any sheet in the same workbook. Obviously you would normally put it close to the input values, so if you use Z2 and Z3 as per my example formula might be in Z4....

Comment: Note: I'm using MATCH with a final argument of 0 - that means the input values in Z2 and Z3 must match exactly with row and column headers, it's possible to get a "closest match" [in fact next lowest] by using 1 as the 3rd argument of MATCH, but if you do that the column and row headers should be in ascending order

Comment: @ Andrew Wade, sorry if any of that goes over your head, please query anything that doesn't make sense to you, happy to explain (or I'm sure Alistair will too)